# How to use @Html.Raw() in @Html.TextAreaFor()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, summernote

I am using summernote to add Image, Video, text. Also, I save image or video as  Html Code that is type string to database. When I retreive video or image from the database to display on summernote, it takes nearly 5 minutes and I don't know why. However, when I retrieve text from the database to display on summernote, there is no problem.

Here is model

```
public class Article
{
   [AllowHtml]
   [Column(TypeName = "varchar(MAX)")]
   public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Here is View for summernote editor

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => Model.Content, new { @class = "", placeholder = @Blog.Helper.Resources.Content, @id = "summernote_1" })
```

In addition, If I use this below code in View

```
<div id="summernote_1">@Html.Raw(Model.Content)</div>
```

No problem with displaying video or image, but I cannot edit summernote. When I edit summernote, Model.Content is getting null.

If I use this below code in View

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => Model.Content, new { @class = "", placeholder = @Blog.Helper.Resources.Content, @id = "summernote_1" })
```

No problem with editing summernote, but displaying video or image takes nearly 5 minute.

Because of these reasons, I am trying to use this below code in View however this below code is getting error.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => Html.Raw(Model.Content), new { @class = "", placeholder = @Blog.Helper.Resources.Content, @id = "summernote_1" })
```

Can I use html.raw in html.TextAreaFor or What can I do for this issue to display video or image and edit summernote.
Sorry my bad english and I hope that someone can help me.

Comment: "Code is getting error" - what error found there? I think you can't use `Html.Raw` with `TextAreaFor` - check if this issue similar to yours: https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/1481.

Comment: Error is "Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.". I am looking link that you add.

Answer (score 6):

`Html.Raw` method returns `System.Web.IHtmlString`, I think what you need is just passing `string` property containing HTML tags (AFAIK `Html.Raw` helper can't be used inside other HTML helpers like `DisplayFor` or `TextBoxFor`).

It is possible to use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` for `Content` property before `TextAreaFor` as shown by this example (especially if HTML tags are unknowingly encoded):

```
@model Article

@{
    Model.Content = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.Content);
}

@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Content, new { @class = "", placeholder = @Blog.Helper.Resources.Content, @id = "summernote_1" })
```

By using this way, you can render HTML tags properly from viewmodel's string property without losing model binding.

Comment: Unfortunately, it can edit successfully but same problem is going on. When displaying image or video, it takes so much time.

Comment: Thanks, HttpUtility.HtmlDecode is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

> .textarea {
>           padding: 2px;
>           width: 250px;
>           height: 200px;
>           border: solid 1px #e0e0eb;
>           overflow: scroll;
>           overflow-y: scroll;
>           overflow-x: hidden;
>       }

write your html content using @Html.Raw() inside a div that contains a class "textarea".

`<div class="textarea"> @Html.Raw(Model.NOTE) </div>`