# How to render encoded HTML string in @Html.TextArea(<div>Here is the text</div>)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view

I have a requirement to show Raw HTML string with HTML in TextArea in form ASP.Net MVC Razor view. Raw HTML I am getting from `@model.AnyProperties`.

How can I render them show in text area.

```
@Html.TextArea("myTextArea", "Here I am giving raw html string(HTML tags as string)", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Output : should render raw HTML tags and shows in text area.

Like `@Html.Raw(HTMLString)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use @Html.Raw() in @Html.TextAreaFor()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48377588/how-to-use-html-raw-in-html-textareafor)

Comment: Its not working @owen.